# TSQL Decimal To Text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following field called - Amount. It's a decimal(18,2).

So a value of 70.26

What I want to create for the sake of a file out is something like -

00000007026

Where it's a varchar (11), with leading zeros to make up the 11 characters, if only 4 exist in the example above, but also I want the decimal removed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000000' + REPLACE(CAST(Amount AS VARCHAR(11)),'.',''),11)
```

---

### Explanation

The `CAST` transforms the number into a string, for further manipulations.

The `REPLACE` removes the decimal point.

The I add 11 zeros, no matter what will be the number here. But taking only 11 characters from the `RIGHT`, will give what you want.

This will not work for negative numbers, as the zeros will be added at the left of the `-` sign.

Comment: I will let you take care of the case when the number is actually longer than 11 characters, it is not very clear to me what you want to do with it if it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @str varchar(11)

set @str='00000000000'

declare @p decimal(18,2)

set @p=70.80


select RIGHT(@str+replace(cast(@p as varchar),'.',''), 11  )
```